# Android Market application Url?

Tags: android, url, google-play

Is there right way to get Url to android market app ?
I read some answer here  but I did not  success to get any ?

Answer (score 11, accepted):

**For phones:**

```
market://search?q=pname:[name of your package here]
```

For example:

```
market://search?q=pname:net.mandaria.tippytipper
```

**For non-phones:**  You'll need to link to an Android Market aggregator such as appbrain:

```
http://www.appbrain.com/app/net.mandaria.tippytipper
```

Comment: this method stopped working for me.  had to switch to emmby's answer beleow

Comment: this is no longer the preferred way.  see emmby's answer below.

Answer (score 42):

Bryan's market URL will work, but I prefer:

```
market://details?id=com.example.your.package
```

since it will take you directly to the details page.

Comment: We can use com.vending.google or market:// to create an intent and start google play ... package name is on the manifest but how can I get every url or app schema of every application installed ? how to know their respective 'market://' ?

Answer (score 7):

This should work as a standard HTML anchor tag:

```
https://market.android.com/search?q=pname:[name of your package here]
```

IE:

```
https://market.android.com/search?q=pname:com.google.earth
```

Similar to Bryan Denny's answer on 10/29/2010, but in regular URL format, and not the special `market://` style link.

Answer (score 4):

See http://developer.android.com/distribute/googleplay/promote/linking.html

Basically, from a web site use:

```
http://play.google.com/store/apps/details?id=&lt;package_name>
```

From an android app use:

```
market://details?id=&lt;package_name>
```

Comment: This is the most current now, all the market.android.com/... links should be avoided.

Answer (score 1):

the apps are hosted on their own sites. you can download the apps from your android mobile by visiting the market place.

Answer (score 1):

```
https://market.android.com/details?id=com.somecompany.someapp
```

replace `com.somecompany.someapp` with your app package

Answer (score 0):

Example for Apps details page:

If you go

```
https://market.android.com/details?id=com.somecompany.someapp
```

it redirects to the Google Play store

```
https://play.google.com/store/apps/details?id=com.somecompany.someapp
```